# How to see if ComboBox is in DropDown State?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have searched several forums but did not find answer for checking whether ComboBox is already `DroppedDown` via `VBA code`.
I have other code on `Form_KeyDown` events due to which anytime I press `vbKeyDown` it moves to next record. I need to check if `ComboBox` is `DroppedDown` then don't use other code and instead treat the default functionality of access where `vbKeyDown` will start scrolling through the items of `ComboBox` displayed in `DropDown`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such property, neither an event for *OnDropDown* or similar.

If the combobox has focus, you can force a dropdown using the *DropDown* method, but that's as close you can get.